# How to get the hostname from a url with accented letters inside in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following url inside a field of model:

`https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/i6ix3x/trenitalia_sostiene_che_potrà_non_rispettare_il/?sort=new`

Inside the URL there is an accented letter (à). If I use URI.parse to get hostname gives me the following error:

`URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only "https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/i6ix3x/trenitalia_sostiene_che_potr\u00E0_non_rispettare_il/?sort=new"`

The method URL.encode resolves the problem, but I discover that the URL.encode is obsolete and should not be used.

Which method should I use for replacing URI.encode?

Answer (score 0):

this is encoding issue and you need to do it as below

first lets encode your URI first

encoded_url = URI.encode('https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/i6ix3x/trenitalia_sostiene_che_potrà_non_rispettare_il/?sort=new')

And then parse it

URI.parse(encoded_url)

good luck

Comment: URI.encode is obsolete and should not be used (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/238b979f1789f95262a267d8df6239806f2859cc).

Comment: try this if it works i will edit my post

require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("yourlink")
p uri
p uri.scheme
p uri.host

Comment: It works but this solution doesn't pass the check of Rubocop (https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.85/cops_lint.html#linturiescapeunescape)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be an inelegant solution:

```rb
URI.parse(URI.extract(target.url).first)
# => #<URI::HTTPS https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/i6ix3x/trenitalia_sostiene_che_potr>
```

Then I use the method `host`

```rb
URI.parse(URI.extract(target.url).first).host
# => "www.reddit.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I find uses the gem Addressable(https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable):

`Addressable::URI.parse('https://www.reddit.com/r/italy/comments/i6ix3x/trenitalia_sostiene_che_potrà_non_rispettare_il/?sort=new').host`